# MySQL 1273 Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have initially started to run https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S_tz1z_5bA&t and installed it all. When using MySQL Work Bench I initially run it, I get thunder icon when it runs but then I get an error.

```
11:19:58    CREATE TABLE `payment_methods` (   `payment_method_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`payment_method_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_ci   Error Code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_ci'   0.00041 sec
```

Error Code: 1273 Seems to be the issue.. There are 4 SQL bits and only one is called back.

[MySQL Work Bench 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q13u0.png)

[MySQL Work Bench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61HSH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old version of MySQL - it doesn't support `utf8mb4` which was added in 2010.

Either update MySQL to at least version 5.5.3 or use `utf8` instead (but some special characters, in particular emoji, won't be stored properly).